# Refuse to answer questions at border control

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, uk-citizens, borders

When returning from a long holiday, rather than the usual cursory glance at the passport and wave through, the person behind the passport control desk started asking a whole load of rather intrusive questions. I am a British citizen returning to the UK. I didn't feel like telling a complete stranger about my life so I just gave some short snippy general answers.
Is it acceptable to just tell them its none of their business and walk away? 
(Note: this is specifically for the U.K. not the US as the other questions I found)

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie None of that in any way invalidates the question of a British citizen who wants to know their legal rights when speaking to a British official.

Comment: How could it possibly be acceptable to walk away?  You can't enter the UK until the officer has cleared you, right?  Are you going to walk back into the departure lounge and fly to a different country instead?

Comment: I would ask this on Law...

Comment: I think OP is asking if UK is similar to the US in that CPB cannot prevent a US Citizen from entering the US.  They can make it difficult, but can't stop it.

Comment: @motoDrizzt it's obviously on topic in both places.  I suspect that this question is more likely to attract the attention of someone knowledgeable about UK immigration law than a question asked there would be.

Comment: @Johns-305, the CBP can prevent an US citizen from entering if they falsely believe that the person is not a citizen. If a CBP official says "this passport looks fishy," the citizen will face a lengthy delay at best.

Comment: @Johns-305 there's a possible difference in the US, though, which is that the immigration inspector typically asks questions in connection with the customs form, and makes some notation on it.  US citizens must be admitted, but they're not immune from inspection and interrogation on customs questions.  I don't think UK immigration inspectors concern  themselves with customs matters, though I am not certain about that.

Comment: Besides establishing your identity, isn't the purpose of questioning to determine if you are carrying any items that may be restricted from entering or to see if you need to pay customs on any items? I would think that a good answer would talk about what questions are relevant to a UK border crossing and which ones are not, so far I don't see that.

Comment: If this happened recently, it may be just due to higher security risks in the UK right now. Did you by chance travel to any country in the middle east or north africa? Then this could have been done as a precaution. I would be happy too if my border control inspects their own citizens too in case they travel to suspicious areas. Keep in mind that there are lot of people returning back from ISIS and being a citizen is not enough to let them roam back in the country.

Comment: I had a similar issue but when boarding a flight from the UK to Spain. Going through security I got pulled aside for a grilling. When they started asking questions, I told them I'd only respond if I was legally required to. After some snippiness from them and a  "Well, read this" (while pointing at the Terrorism act), I challenged them on their questions ("It says you can ask questions pertinent to the safety of the plane. How does knowing the identity of the person I'm visiting in Spain do that?"). After some more muttering I was told to move along.

Comment: Schedule 7 of the Terrorism Act 2000 can get nasty if they don't like you https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2017/may/17/cage-campaign-group-director-muhammed-rabbani-charged-under-terrorism-act .

Comment: @Johns-305 Even though it was intended to stop exactly this, sadly the Geneva convention (which among other things insures the right of a citizen to enter their country) seems to not always apply in a post 9-11 world.

Comment: I have yet to read what kind of "intrusive questions" those were. Of course they can ask you were you went and to do what, less likely whether you had sex with your wife during your travel...

Comment: @corsiKa Well, no.  The Geneva Convention is pretty much irrelevant as it is US law that gives US Citizens the unexceptional right to enter.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The Home Office was asked in 2015, [what the legal basis for such questioning is](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/legal_basis_for_questions_asked). Here is their answer.

> Assuming that you are an EEA national, Border Force officers can ask you any 
>   questions that allow them to establish your identity and nationality. This may include 
>   questions about your travel history. The EEA Regulations 2006 specify that an EEA 
>   national must produce a valid passport or identity card to establish their nationality and identity however if does not specify how the Border officer should establish the validity of these travel documents. Questioning EEA passengers is one of the ways that Border Force officers can quickly verify if a document is likely to be valid.

I think it is fair to summarize that general questions about your recent travel history and other matters relating to your identity are fair game. This might include your place of birth, place of residence, *et c*. You may be entitled to decline to answer more invasive questions.

---

> I am a British citizen returning to the UK. I didn't feel like telling a complete stranger about my life so I just gave some short snippy general answers.

I think that is a very British response.

As a pragmatic answer, I suggest you use the e-gates, because there you (usually) don't have to talk to anyone. These days I leave my earphones in from plane seat to home, and the airport staff get the message that I don't want to talk.

> Is it acceptable to just tell them its none of their business and walk away?

It is not acceptable to walk away. In principle you, as a British citizen, do not need anyone's permission to enter the UK, but you are not going to get very far until you have satisfied the Border Force that you are a British citizen.

From personal anecdote, I once declined to answer "Where have you come from today?" on the basis that I could not remember. (It was a long week.) The officer looked more sympathetic than suspicious.

---

If you are unhappy with the questioning you receive, you can ask to speak with the Border Force Duty Manager for the terminal in question, although this is unlikely to expedite your entry.

Comment: +1 for use the electronic border gates. I'd be tempted to suggest *not* using the electronic border gates with a passport that purports to be electronic might itself be suspicious - why on earth would a holder of a passport that actually works in such gates want to queue?

Comment: @abligh Try travelling with my dad, he can't use a mobile phone let alone an electronic gate. On a serious note, at MAN the airport now has a firm policy of refusing to let you use the desks if you are eligible to use an e-gate. You will be stuck in a long queue of people who do not know how to use an electronic gate while border staff wait around doing nothing.

Comment: +1 in general, but also for the "I think that is a very British response."

Comment: Wow, I would expect "I don't remember" to "Where have you come from today" to raise a blood-red flag! How did you pull that one off!

Comment: @Mehrdad Suitably disheveled look, bloodshot eyes, dark circles under the eyes, etc.? Also delivered with the appropriate intonation and accent, of course.

Comment: Maybe your passport said Amsterdam or something.

Comment: @abligh if you are a minor or in a family group that includes minors, you can't use the e-gates. Even if everyone in the group has a suitable passport...

Comment: @abligh, there are plenty of reasons, ranging from the purely pragmatic (they never ever recognise me: I'm not sure whether it's because my passport photo has glasses or because they don't like beards) to the ideological (either generally Luddite or specifically anti-gate on the basis that they're more likely to have false positives than a trained human).

Comment: @PeterTaylor The UK e-gates are run by a human. Four gates per person. He has a video feed from each gate, and the passport details are fed to him along with the video feed. The Border Force officer makes the decision to let you in or not. After the egates, turn around and you'll see a couple of booths where they are sitting.

Comment: @Calchas interesting! Makes complete sense but I never thought of that. I presume the passport is presented to the controller once scanner, together with the photo taken, and the computer's view of whether the photos match and/or photo taken matches whatever biometrics is in the chip?

Comment: @abligh: I _always_ avoid the e-gates, because they basically never work (for me). If you find me in the e-gate queue, it's only because I've determined that it's quickest for me to use _that_ queue then get waved through by a person at a stand-by desk when my e-gate attempt inevitably failed. I just balance the odds of that being faster than reaching the front of the "normal" queue (which it normally is).

Comment: The EEA regulations don't generally apply to British citizens.

Comment: @anomuse Border Force staff can talk to me if they like, but I have little patience with the airport people re-arranging those elastic barriers.

Answer (score 22):

The interviewer has to establish that you **are** a British citizen, that your passport is genuine and that it genuinely belongs to you. Often this is done with the cursory glance you mention, but there could have been *something* to make him or her wonder.

Asking questions is one way to go about this inquiry. A genuine citizens with a genuine passport should be able to give the expeced answers. They don't necessarily expect *coherent* answers at 0030hrs, just typical ones. If that is enough to resolve the concerns, the immigration officer thanks the citizen and takes no further steps.

Saying absolutely nothing would not be a typical response and might cause further inquiries and delays.

Comment: So in some sense that short snippy answer was the best thing to do, since many people here agree that it is a "very British response"?

Comment: FYI, "0-dark-30" already means "in the morning" (indeed, that's the entire purpose of the "dark"), so your "in the morning" is redundant.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, I wanted to use the informal expression, but many readers here might not be familiar with it.

Comment: That's.... a strange rationale. But to each their own.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the user may have [wanted to have fun with the term in question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8931/what-does-zero-dark-thirty-mean)

Answer (score -2):

Just ask them if they have any reason to believe your passport is not genuine, and, whatever answer they give, be it in the affirmative or not, politely tell them that you refuse to be interviewed in a public space (which passport control area is), and request that, if they have any questions, you require an interview room.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is likely to be entirely counterproductive to the OP's actual aim, which is to get through passport control as quickly as possible and with as little human interaction as possible.